# Using when while dealing with strings and sub-strings in Pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe in `pyspark` like below.

```
df.show()

+---+----+----+------------+
| id|name|city|      ip_add|
+---+----+----+------------+
|  1| sam| Hyd|  191.10.0.1|
|  2| Tim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|
|  3| Jim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|
|  4| sam| SFO|222.19.18.15|
|  5|same| HOU| 12.10.12.07|
+---+----+----+------------+
```

I want to populate some columns based on certain lists.
Lists are below.

```
name_list = ['sam']
city_list = ['Mum']
ip_list = ['191.10', '10.0']
```

Conditions to populate new columns

1. Populate column `name_check` If `name` is equal to `sam` then `Y` else `N`.
2. Populate column `city_check` if `city` is equal to `Mum` then `Y` else `N`.
3. Populate column `ip_check` if `ip_add` first two number sets are equal to `191.10` or `10.0` then `Y` else `N`.

I defined a function like below. I want to use the same function so I won't have to duplicate the code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
def new_column(df, compare_list, column_to_add, column_to_check):
    final_df = df.withColumn(column_to_add, when(df[column_to_check].isin(compare_list), "Y").otherwise('N'))
    return final_df
```

First column `name_check` variables:

```
name_column_to_add = 'name_check'
name_column_to_check = 'name'
```

Invoking the function:

```
name_df = new_column(df, name_list, name_column_to_add, name_column_to_check)
name_df.show()

+---+----+----+------------+----------+
| id|name|city|      ip_add|name_check|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+
|  1| sam| Hyd|  191.10.0.1|         Y|
|  2| Tim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|
|  3| Jim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|
|  4| sam| SFO|222.19.18.15|         Y|
|  5|same| HOU| 12.10.12.07|         N|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+
```

Second column `city_check` variables:

```
city_column_to_add = 'city_check'
city_column_to_check = 'city'
```

Invoking the function:

```
city_df = new_column(name_df, city_list, city_column_to_add, city_column_to_check)
city_df.show()

+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+
| id|name|city|      ip_add|name_check|city_check|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+
|  1| sam| Hyd|  191.10.0.1|         Y|         N|
|  2| Tim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|         Y|
|  3| Jim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|         Y|
|  4| sam| SFO|222.19.18.15|         Y|         N|
|  5|same| HOU| 12.10.12.07|         N|         N|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+
```

Third column `ip_check` variables:

```
ip_column_to_add = 'ip_check'
ip_column_to_check = 'ip_add'
```

Invoking the function:

```
ip_df = new_column(city, ip_list, ip_column_to_add, ip_column_to_check)
ip_df.show()

+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
| id|name|city|      ip_add|name_check|city_check|ip_check|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
|  1| sam| Hyd|  191.10.0.1|         Y|         N|       N|
|  2| Tim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|         Y|       N|
|  3| Jim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|         Y|       N|
|  4| sam| SFO|222.19.18.15|         Y|         N|       N|
|  5|same| HOU| 12.10.12.07|         N|         N|       N|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
```

Expected_result:

```
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
| id|name|city|      ip_add|name_check|city_check|ip_check|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
|  1| sam| Hyd|  191.10.0.1|         Y|         N|       Y|
|  2| Tim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|         Y|       Y|
|  3| Jim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|         Y|       Y|
|  4| sam| SFO|222.19.18.15|         Y|         N|       N|
|  5|same| HOU| 12.10.12.07|         N|         N|       N|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
```

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: It seems that for the first two (`name` and `city`) you want an exact match but for the `ip_add` you want a partial match. Is that correct?

Comment: @Shaido Yes That is what I want. I would like to use the same `function` though for all the `3` lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the modified working code of yours

```
name_list = ['sam']
city_list = ['Mum']
ip_list = ['191.10', '10.0']

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
def new_column(df, compare_list, column_to_add, column_to_check):
    final_df = df.withColumn(column_to_add, f.when(column_to_check.isin(compare_list), "Y").otherwise('N'))
    return final_df

name_column_to_add = 'name_check'
name_column_to_check = 'name'

name_df = new_column(df, name_list, name_column_to_add, f.col(name_column_to_check))

city_column_to_add = 'city_check'
city_column_to_check = 'city'

city_df = new_column(name_df, city_list, city_column_to_add, f.col(city_column_to_check))

ip_column_to_add = 'ip_check'
ip_column_to_check = 'ip_add'

ip_df = new_column(city_df, ip_list, ip_column_to_add, f.concat_ws('.', f.split(f.col(ip_column_to_check), '\\.')[0], f.split(f.col(ip_column_to_check), '\\.')[1]))

ip_df.show()
```

All you had to do was to *substring* the *ip address* to get only the *first two digits splitted by .* for that I have used `split` and `concat_ws` function and then modified your `new_column` function to accept last parameter as `column`

So you should have now

```
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
| id|name|city|      ip_add|name_check|city_check|ip_check|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
|  1| sam| Hyd|  191.10.0.1|         Y|         N|       Y|
|  2| Tim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|         Y|       Y|
|  3| Jim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|         Y|       Y|
|  4| sam| SFO|222.19.18.15|         Y|         N|       N|
|  5|same| HOU| 12.10.12.07|         N|         N|       N|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: A simpler solution compared to the one I was working on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring_index` to compare with the part of ip address. Here is slightly better version of your code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn

// create sample data
data = [
  (1, "sam", "Hyd", "191.10.0.1"),
  (2, "Tim", "Mum", "10.0.0.1"),
  (3, "Jim", "Mum", "10.0.0.1"),
  (4, "sam", "SFO", "222.19.18.15"),
  (5, "same", "HOU", "12.10.12.07")
  ]

// create dataframe
df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(["id", "name", "city", "ip_add"])
df.show()

// add compare lists
name_list = ['sam']
city_list = ['Mum']
ip_list = ['191.10', '10.0']

// add checks
// notice usage of subtring_index to get part of ip address
checks = [
  (df.name, name_list, "name_check"),
  (df.city, city_list, "city_check"),
  (fn.substring_index(df.ip_add, '.', 2), ip_list, "ip_check")
]

// add column checks to the original dataframe
for (col_to_check, col_check_list, col_add) in checks:
  df = df.withColumn(col_add, fn.when(col_to_check.isin(col_check_list), "Y").otherwise('N'))
```

Results

```
df.show()
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
| id|name|city|      ip_add|name_check|city_check|ip_check|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
|  1| sam| Hyd|  191.10.0.1|         Y|         N|       Y|
|  2| Tim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|         Y|       Y|
|  3| Jim| Mum|    10.0.0.1|         N|         Y|       Y|
|  4| sam| SFO|222.19.18.15|         Y|         N|       N|
|  5|same| HOU| 12.10.12.07|         N|         N|       N|
+---+----+----+------------+----------+----------+--------+
```